# Circular dependency: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context

Tags: dependency-injection, di

I have a custom module.

On 1 installation (all others work) I get the error, that there's a circular dependency.

YES: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context is a dependency in my Controller because `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` needs it.

But I don't understand the other way around.

clearing var/di, var/generation and var/cache didn't help

## EDIT:

this is the module: https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login

this is the exception:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Circular dependency: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context depends on bitExpert\ForceCustomerLogin\Controller\LoginCheck and vice versa.

Exception #0 (LogicException): Circular dependency: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context depends on bitExpert\ForceCustomerLogin\Controller\LoginCheck and vice versa.
#0 /home/psander/projects/forcelogin_nz/backup/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#1 /home/psander/projects/forcelogin_nz/backup/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 /home/psander/projects/forcelogin_nz/backup/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'context', 'bitExpert\\Force...')
#3 /home/psander/projects/forcelogin_nz/backup/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('bitExpert\\Force...', Array, Array)
#4 /home/psander/projects/forcelogin_nz/backup/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('bitExpert\\Force...')
#5 /home/psander/projects/forcelogin_nz/backup/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('bitExpert\\Force...')
#6 /home/psander/projects/forcelogin_nz/backup/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'bitExpert\\Force...', NULL, 'loginCheckContr...', 'bitExpert\\Force...')
#7 /home/psander/projects/forcelogin_nz/backup/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('bitExpert\\Force...', Array, Array)
#8 /home/psander/projects/forcelogin_nz/backup/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('bitExpert\\Force...')
```

Comment: how can a framework class depend on your class?

Comment: @Marius well.... that's excatly what confues me.

Comment: do you have 2 classes named `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`? One in vendor one in lib that might be modified? I don't know, I'm shooting in the dark here

Comment: definitly not in my module. do you think it's possible that it might be another module causeing the error?